# Created a singleton, can't seem to use it in my web application

Tags: java, singleton

I created a singleton according to how 'effective java' says to do it: https://sites.google.com/site/io/effective-java-reloaded (see slides around page 35 I think)

So my enum singleton class looks like:

```
public enum MySettings {
    INSTANCE;


    private int someValue;

    private MySettings() {
        someValue = 10;
    }

    public int getSomeValue() {
        return someValue;
    }
}
```

Now I tried to use it in a class but it errors out during runtime:

```
public class MongoDaoImpl implements MongoDao {
    private int mongoConnectionPoolSize = MySettings.INSTANCE.getSomeValue();
}
```

Why does it fail here?

The point of my singleton is to hold config related information so I can use it to set configuration type values so I don't have to hard coded them.

I'm getting an error for MongoDaoImpl:

```
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Could not initialize class MongoDaoImpl
sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:39)
    sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:27)
    java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:513)
    org.springframework.beans.BeanUtils.instantiateClass(BeanUtils.java:126)
```

Comment: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Could not initialize class MongoDaoImpl

Answer (score 2):

You're trying to affect an int to a String. That can't compile. Either the `getSomeValue()` method must return a String, or the `mongoConnectionPoolSize` must be an int.

Answer (score 0):

Because you declared the property with `String`, and your method returns an `int`

Answer (score 0):

`getSomeValue()` returns an `int`, and you're trying to assign it to a variable of type `String`, so there's a type error. But that should actually occur at compile time.

Why does `mongoConnectionPoolSize` have the type String? Sounds like it should be `int`.

What is the actual error message you get?

**Update:** It looks like you want the class `MongoDaoImpl` to be instantiated by Spring. For that, it needs a public no-arguments constructor. Does it have one? It doesn't look like the problem has anything to do with the singleton. It may also be related to the Spring bean configuration.

Comment: sorry I just typed it out wrong, it is just a generic message saying it can't load the servlet and it couldnt' instantiate the Mongo bean.

Comment: @Blankman: type out? Why are you typing up new code with new errors instead of copying the code you have with the errors you need help with? As for the error, look at the log file of your servlet container, it should contain more details.

Comment: @MichaelBorgwardt I can't post client code that's why, thanks for  your help i'll look.

Comment: The error in MongoDaoImpl is: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Could not initialize class sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
 sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:39)
 sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:27)
 java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:513)
 org.springframework.beans.BeanUtils.instantiateClass(BeanUtils.java:126)

Comment: @Blankman: See updated answer. And you really should mention essential facts about your setup like using Spring.

Comment: @MichaelBorgwardt yes I should have mentioned that, but the problem was me overlooking how spring was relevant and it is now obvious as the spring container is in charge of object creation etc. thanks for the tip.

Comment: My class MySettings is not registered as a bean, it has to interface etc., how can I make this work?  confused...

Comment: @Blankman: If you're using Spring, you should probably not implement the Singleton pattern manually and instead simply configure it as a spring bean with singleton scope, i.e. Spring will always inject the same instance.